# When I click a button different button flashes in kivy recycleview

Tags: python, kivy

So, I know there have been couple of similar questions but I haven't found a solution on any of those questions.
When I click one button in my RecycleView screen in my kivy app different button flashes. I haven't changed anything about buttons so I don't see any mistake in my code but there might be something that I have not seen.
Here is the code:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.app import App

class Kupci_sve(RecycleView, Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Kupci_sve, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{"text": str(i)} for i in range(20)]
        self.bar_width = 8
        self.scroll_type = ['bars']


kv = Builder.load_string('''
<Kupci_sve>:
    name: 'kupci_sve'
    viewclass: 'Button'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: (None, 100)
        default_size_hint: (1, None)
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: "vertical"

        ''')


class app(App):
    def build(self):
        return Kupci_sve()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app().run()
```

I import this screen to my main.py file and run it from there but I didn't paste that code because I think it has nothing to do with this problem. If you need any other info, just tell me. Thank you.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: here, I deleted unnecessary stuff.

Comment: That is not a [mcve]. Please read the linked information. The posted code should be complete, so that someone can copy/paste the code and run it.

Comment: here, copy/paste it, it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a minimal, complete, reproducible example, I suspect your problem may be in making your `Kupci_sve` class extend both `Screen` and `RecycleView`. A better approach would be to just extend `Screen` and simply include a `RecycleView` in the `kv` rule for `<Kupci_sve>`.

Here is what I mean:

```
<Kupci_sve>:
    name: 'kupci_sve'
    RecycleView:
        id: rv   # added id
        bar_width: 8
        scroll_type: ['bars']
        viewclass: 'Button'
        RecycleBoxLayout:
            default_size: (None, 100)
            default_size_hint: (1, None)
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            orientation: "vertical"
```

And the `Kupci_sve` class becomes:

```
class Kupci_sve(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Kupci_sve, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ids.rv.data = [{"text": str(i), "on_release":partial(self.butt_release, i)} for i in range(20)]

    def butt_release(self, index):
        print('butt_release:', index)
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried but when I extend it just to Screen it doesn't show RecycleView buttons, it's just black screen. But thanks! I edited the post so now you can copy/paste it and try it.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you! And is there a way now for me to use these buttons for, for example, popup windows? Like to connect them to other stuff.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much for your help!